# Media Player crash after use

Tags: android, media-player, midi

I am working on a small application that plays back eight different .5 second midi files. I have an ontouch action that gets called everytime a specified object gets touched and within that I have an if/else if statement that plays the specified midi file depending on the object touched. When I run this, It works fine for the first several touches but after a while the playback stops, and then the app eventually crashes. What is going wrong here?

Basic Structure:

```
public ontouch(){   
    if (something >= 3){  
         mediaplayer s = mediaplayer.create(somethingmidi2);  
         s.start();  
    }else if (something < 3){
         mediaplayer s = mediaplayer.create(somethingmidi);  
         s.start();  
    }
 } `
```

Comment: What happens if `something == 3`? For that matter, what's `something`? Further, both sections of your `if/else` do the same thing.

Comment: Fixed. Just typed that psuedo code out quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a guess, but you probably aren't calling the `release()` method of the media player, nor `reset()` when you are reinitializing it.

Comment: No, I'm not. I thought that didn't matter until the end of the function. Should I be calling that before each time? Would that reduce the slight delay I am currently experiencing?

Comment: Ignore the delay part, I retested and realized there actually was no delay. Would the release keep it from crashing?

Comment: From what I have been reading it is only necessary to call the release method. What would be the advantage of using the reset?